# Yesod app in Docker container can't make network requests

Tags: haskell, docker, yesod, amazon-ses

I have a Yesod app which I am deploying to Heroku in a Docker container.  The app uses Amazon SES to send emails.  When running the app locally using yesod devel this works fine, but in the container on Heroku I get the following error:

```
HttpExceptionRequest Request {
  host                 = "email.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
  port                 = 443
  secure               = True
  requestHeaders       = [("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-
urlencoded"),("Date","Wed, 20 Sep 2017 12:39:49 +0000"),("X-Amzn-
Authorization","AWS3-HTTPS AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIBUN4ZEOKYKOB35A, 
Algorithm=HmacSHA256, 
Signature=xh3fi4EJOAe0LOZVCng5NRZIw2D+6P++0aO4Q5Dy0gw=")]
  path                 = "/"
  queryString          = ""
  method               = "POST"
  proxy                = Nothing
  rawBody              = False
  redirectCount        = 10
  responseTimeout      = ResponseTimeoutDefault
  requestVersion       = HTTP/1.1
}
 (ConnectionFailure Network.BSD.getProtocolByName: does not exist (no 
such protocol name: tcp))
```

I'm thinking I might need to install some extra packages in the container.  Here's the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:17.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpq-dev

WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app

EXPOSE 8080

ENV PGHOST localhost

CMD "./run"
```

Comment: I'm on mobile right now and so I don't know the exact package name, but you need to install the apt package that provides /etc/protocols

Comment: Thanks, that gives me somewhere to start looking!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to Michael Snoyman's hint, I found that `netbase` is the package required to populate `/etc/protocols`.  After installing that, I got a new error complaining that the SSL cert for Amazon SES was from an unknown certificate authority.

I installed the `ca-certificates` package, and this went away.  I also came across an error telling me that `libstdc++6` was not installed - so I installed that. All working now.

My final `Dockerfile` that works with Yesod, using email auth and Amazon SES to send emails, is as follows (the "run" command is the compiled executable from `stack build`):

```
FROM ubuntu:17.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpq-dev libgnutls30 netbase libstdc++6 ca-certificates

WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app

EXPOSE 8080

ENV PGHOST localhost

CMD "./run"
```

Hooray for trial and error :)